# EF6 1:optional + 1:many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

got a little Problem with EF6 Code First (in a MVC Web App).

Enum to classify an Account in a "AccountCircle":

```
public enum AccountType
    {
        Circle1,
        Circle2,
        Circle3,
        Circle4,
        Circle5
    }
```

Main class for Accounts:

```
[Table("Accounts")]
public class AccountModel
{
  public AccountModel()
  {
  }

  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

The main Company-Model

```
[Table("Companys")]
public class CompanyModel
{
    public CompanyModel()
    {
        this.AccountCircle = new AccountCircleModel();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int? idAccountCircle { get; set; }
    public AccountCircleModel AccountCircle { get; set; }
}
```

Class for a single circle:

```
[Table("AccountCircles")]
public class AccountCircleModel
{
    public AccountCircleModel()
    {
        this.Member = new List<AccountCirleMemberModel>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }


    public int idCompany { get; set; }
    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }

    public List<AccountCirleMemberModel> Member { get; set; }
}
```

and last but not least the account itself with an additinal information what type of member:

```
[Table("AccountCircleMember")]
public class AccountCirleMemberModel
{
    public AccountCirleMemberModel()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public AccountType Typ { get; set; }

    public int idAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountModel Account { get; set; }


    public int idAccountCircle { get; set; }
    public AccountCircleModel AccountCircle { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // modelBuilder Infos.....

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }



    #region Tables

    public DbSet<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyModel> Companys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountCircleModel> AccountCircles { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

So there is a Company, which has an optional property of type "AccountCircle" (1:optional)
In the Accountcircle, there is a List of Accounts with a separate enum (AccountCirleMemberModel 1:many)

I tried hundred of modelBuilder methods to give the EF6 the necessary infos, but no success.
Has someone a hint, to give the DbModelBuilder in the "protected override void OnModelCreating" method the correct relations data?

Big thanks in advance!
monte

Comment: What do you need actually?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but if you want to specify the relationships between tables in the DB, using EF Code First, you have to use modifier `virtual` for your "navigation" properties - those that map  to another table. So the code would look like:

```
[Table("Companys")]
public class CompanyModel
{
    // other properties and the rest of the code here

    public virtual AccountCircleModel AccountCircle { get; set; }
}

[Table("AccountCircles")]
public class AccountCircleModel
{
    // other properties and the rest of the code here

    public virtual CompanyModel Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountCirleMemberModel> Member { get; set; }
}

[Table("AccountCircleMember")]
public class AccountCirleMemberModel
{
    // other properties and the rest of the code here

    public virtual AccountModel Account { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountCircleModel AccountCircle { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need to add properties that would serve as foreign keys - EF would take care of that. You could specify them, but then you'd have to use fluent API to map those properties as foreign keys for specific tables.